# Insert query fails to insert data in table

Tags: mysql, node.js, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using node.js to register user into my react native app. There doesn't seem to be any error as the select query is working fine and i am able to login. But when i try to insert the values are not updated in my table. There doesn't seem to any error in the code. The query seems to be working fine in mysql.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql =  require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: '',
      database:'SampleDb',
})


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var phone = req.body.phone;

  connection.query("INSERT INTO reg (id,name,email,password,phone) VALUES (null,'?', '?', '?','?')"),[name,email,password,phone];
});
module.exports = router;
```

This is my react native code

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name:'',
            email:'',
            password:'',
            phone:'',
            }

        };
     Reg = () => {
            fetch('http://192.168.0.20:3000/UserReg', {
             method : 'POST',
                  headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-type': 'application/json',
                  },

                  body: JSON.stringify({
                  email:this.state.email,
                  name:this.state.name,
                  password:this.state.password,
                  phone:this.state.phone,

                  })
            })

            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((res) => {
                  if(res.success=== true){
                  var email = res.message;

                     AsyncStorage.setItem('email', email);
                     Actions.Ideas();}
                     else {
                    alert(res.message);
                }



            })

            .done();

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The table name and field names do not need quotation marks, that may be the problem.

Comment: Even after removing the quotation marks, it is not wokring

Answer (score 0):

The insert query needs to have the data for insertion.

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO 'user'('name', 'email', 'password', 'phone') VALUES (?,?,?,?)", function(err,row,fields) {}
```

should be

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO 'user'('name', 'email', 'password', 'phone') VALUES (?,?,?,?)",
    [name, email, password, phone], 
    function(err,row,fields) {}
```

Or you could try:

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO user SET ?",
    {name: name, email: email, password: password, phone :phone}, 
    function(err,row,fields) {}
```

Refer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row

Comment: I added the [ name, email, password,phone] still not working. The values are not getting updated on the table

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you're inserting values into your query. There many ways to do this, I'd suggest using ES6 template literals to insert your variables into your query string as follows:

```
connection.query(
    `INSERT INTO user ('name', 'email', 'password', 'phone')
     VALUES (${name},${email},${password},${phone})`, 
    function(err,row,fields) { 
         if(err) {
           console.log(err);
         }
      });
```

ref:https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Also, the table user doesn't need quotes around it in the query string

Comment: I tried it but it still not working. Do you think it is the fetch function that i am having trouble with?

Comment: You should use console.log(err) to see what is actually going in the mysql server and what it is returning. updated the answer.

Comment: I am not able to get results anywhere. The remote debugger for react native doesn't give anything and i tried to use node inspector. There is no response either.

Answer (score 0):

Use Like this

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO `patients` (name, email,password,phone)
VALUES ('?', '?', '?','?')");
```